# IE Not Showing Column Widths

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a site I am working on and I am having some trouble with a table.  I have made the cells to vary in width depending on how much data is being shown.  The entire body of the table is rewritten every time the data range changes via `$(ident).html('');`, and each time the `<td>` elements are created with `style='width: <size>px'` (size being added via string concatenation).  Now this seems to be working find as I increase the amount of data, but when I decrease the amount, the cells do not get narrower as they should, although they do load the accurate data.  The header, which is created in an identical way, does reflect the proper cell widths.  In FireFox everything is working properly.  Is there any known bug in IE that would cause it to disregard cell widths when they increase?  If so, is there any workaround?  I was trying to check that the cells had the proper values using the F12 dev tools, but for some reason it does not show any of the generated HTML, and instead shows only the original fetched from the server.

**EDIT:**  I am on IE 9.  Also, I am using the F12 dev tools in IE.  The width needs to be supplied for the cells because my understanding is that this is necessary to make horizontal scrolling available (if there is more data than can be displayed comfortably).  As for the code, there's really not much to show- just a `for` loop that adds `<td style='width: <size>px;'>` (along with some other attributes- primarily borders, classes, and ID), then uses `$(<tbody>).append(<data>);` to put the cells in the table.

**UPDATE:**  I am beginning to think that this problem has something to do with the way that headers work with other data.  It would appear that the same problem may be happening in FF in a less noticeable way- the code resets the header of the table, then figures out the data for the body and sets the content.  It seems that the content is being formatted based on the header section in FireFox, as the sizes I put for the cells doesn't much matter (aside from that if I don't put one they just shrink really small).  Apparently, the issue has something to do with IE not expanding the table to fill the div it is in.

Comment: What IE version? Can you show some code that causes the problem.

Comment: Why use the Microsoft Developer Toolbar when the F12 dev tools supplied with all IE versions since IE8 are better? What IE version are you using?

Comment: Why do you need to specify width attributes? Width isn't supposed to be rendered automatically by the browser in order to display all the datas  ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the version.  See the edit above for more details.